# Building a file upload API on Django with user authentication

Tags: python, django, api, post

I have a Django app that lets a user upload a file and does some processing on it, and I need to write an API for this app. The requirements are:

- The API must accept file uploads (this is really the only thing the API will be responsible for)
- User authentication must be supported, meaning each file uploaded must be associated with an existing Django user

I wrote the first part quite easily by just telling Django to listen for POST'ed data on a specific URL (which I hit by passing a file to `curl`), but that obviously won't give me user auth.

How can I add that in? Should I try something like tastypie since it's for building API's and has support for user auth, even though I will only barely scratch the surface of its functionality with this basic API? Or could I just get away with telling Django to accept a username and password in the POST along with the file? Is there a best practice for authenticating a user through an API built on top of Django?

Comment: Does the whole thing have to happen in one request or can it happen in two phases?

Comment: @koniiiik ideally one request, but if the LOE is much less for two phases, then I'd settle with that. What are you thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on this would be to simply use the `django.contrib.auth` application and before handling the actual file data in the POST request just verify that the POST request also contains valid authentication info. You can do that by calling the `authenticate` function, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate

The above applies in case you want the whole process to happen in a single request. That, however, means that the whole file will be uploaded *before* checking the authentication info. If you can afford to split this into one auth request followed by a file upload, you can just create a view that will take care of the authentication and then protect your file upload view by the `login_required` decorator. This will require sessions...

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's overkill for your application, I would consider using [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) for authentication to your API. There is a django module called [oauth2app](http://hiidef.github.com/oauth2app/) that lets you guard a URL behind oauth authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Auth

- Add an authid for API. Such as url/uploadfile?file=1.txt&authid=xxx
- The auth id can be got from another API with username & password auth.

Please refer to my code for file upload & API auth at [git](https://github.com/ybdesire/SyncFile).